# Validation of entering numbers

Tags: laravel

I have a `textbox` and I want to check when I enter `textbox`, just enter the number. When a user enters a character, a message will appear indicating the number is allowed. And notice the length limit is 15 characters.

```html
<input type="text" data-bind="value:replyNumber" 
           class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg"
           id="identity" name="identity"
           required="true"
           placeholder="------" >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `maxlength` to limit maximum number of characters and `onchange` event to detect whenever user enters or changes the value of `textbox`. You can make this validation just in javascript.

```html
<input type="text" data-bind="value:replyNumber" 
           class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg"
           id="identity" name="identity"
           required="true"
           onchange="handleInputChange()"
           maxlength="15"
           placeholder="------" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Html5 provides default validation in client side for such type of element . Here is how you do it

```
<input type="number" data-bind="value:replyNumber" 
       class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg"
       id="identity" name="identity"
       required="true"
       maxlength="15"
       placeholder="------" >
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to allow only numbers for your input field just simply change the type as a number instead of text. and you can set maxlength attribute to limit the numbers of characters user can input.

```
<input type="number" id="identity" name="identity" maxlength="15">
```

if you want to show an alert or message if user exceeding the particular limit of characters use javascript. in such case, you should remove the maxlength attribute from the input field and let the javascript to handle the things.

```
$("#identity").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.target.value.length==15){
        alert("maxlength reached");
    }
});
```

here I used jquery to show alert if user exceed the number of charaters.